# How to create fade in and fade out effects for TLabel in Delphi

Tags: delphi, effects

When a user click on label, it changes its color for some milliseconds and then returns to its previous color.

How to simulate this effect in Delphi?

Comment: Change the font color of the label in a series of timed handlers triggered by its onclick event.

Comment: Could you describe this technique in detail?

Comment: Like in the answer that's been posted. Only you'll have to fire the timer more than once gradually changing the color each time.

Comment: Thank you, I'm understand what to do.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One way would be set the font color when you click the item. Then start a `TTimer`:

```
Label.Font.Color := <insert your highlight color>;
TimerEffects.Enabled := true;
```

When the timer fires do something like this:

```
TimerEffects.Enabled := false;
Label.Font.Color := clBLack; // whatever color you want to set the label back to
```

Comment: Thank you! My first try was to use sleep in OnClick event, but you proposal is better.